# How to make passport session isAuthenticated() working with Angular ng-view?

Tags: angularjs, passport.js

ok, if you use session, for each route you can check to see if this page is authenticated or not. If not, usually redirect to login page. e.g.

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

    // do any checks you want to in here

    // CHECK THE USER STORED IN SESSION FOR A CUSTOM VARIABLE
    // you can do this however you want with whatever variables you set up
    if (req.user.authenticated)
        return next();

    // IF A USER ISN'T LOGGED IN, THEN REDIRECT THEM SOMEWHERE
    res.redirect('/');
}
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/hello', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
        res.send('look at me!');
    });

};
```

Now the problem is, in the front end i'm using angular.js, the left side of the page is menu buttons, the right side is the ng-view area.
res.redirect('/') is not working for me, it still displays the page just as if it's logged in, has left side menus, except no valid contents in the ng-view area.

Anyone has example to make res.redirect to work with angular.js ?

Thanks !

Comment: server doesn't do redirects in a single page app, it's done client side. return a 400 series response status and let your promise rejections do the client side

Comment: It worked, Thanks very much !